# Context of Fat Arrow vs Skinny Arrow When Calling Another Function in a Callback

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a an event that uses a fat arrow:

```
$('#new-mail-addr').click (event) => @use_new_address(event)
```

This is the function it calls back:

```
  use_new_address: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#mailing-address-div').hide()
```

This is another event that uses a click event but with a skinny arrow in the same file:

```
$(".helper-text-icon").click ()->
  modalId = $(this).data("modal-help-text-id")
  $("#" + modalId).modal("show")
```

Is it because 'this', for the first scenario is making a call another function, which is transferring ownership of 'this' to the new new function? Is the function 'use_new_address' a function object? I looked at some of the other fat vs skinny arrow answers on here, but I couldn't find something for this specific case.

Comment: There is no "ownership" of anything. It's just about how you want the value of `this` inside your function to be set.

Answer (score 0):

## Answering your questions

> Is it because 'this', for the first scenario is making a call another function, which is transferring ownership of 'this' to the new new function?

No. It is used to ensure that `this` refers to the context in which the function was defined (the object), rather than the context in which it is called (the event). By context I mean the closure, but that term is confusing to most JS developers. It's the closest block / function / object / file in which the code is.

> Is the function 'use_new_address' a function object?

I don't know what you mean by this. It is a function defined on an object, which is apparent as it uses `:` rather than `=` to assign the function to it's property.

## Explanation of your code

The fat arrow in coffeescript binds the `this` of the context in which the function is declared to the functions body.

Normally Jquery would place the click event's `eventObject` into the `this` context for the click callback. But in your first example, the fat arrow negates this and binds `this` to be the context in which it is defined:

```
$('#new-mail-addr').click (event) => @use_new_address(event)
```

As the function it calls is on an object, I shall assume the click event is bound to the element in the context of this object.

```
  use_new_address: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#mailing-address-div').hide()
```

In this callback, event is the `eventObject` and `this` is the object on which `use_new_address` is defined.

You could shorten this to:

```
use_new_address: (event) =>
  event.preventDefault()
  $('#mailing-address-div').hide()
```

and

```
$('#new-mail-addr').click @use_new_address
```

---

In your second example, you don't use the `event` object passed to a click event, but instead use `this`, which is the `eventObject` by default in JQuery.

```
$(".helper-text-icon").click ()->
  modalId = $(this).data("modal-help-text-id")
  $("#" + modalId).modal("show")
```

## TLDR;

There is lot's of good reading on fat arrows in Coffeescript, take a look at [this](http://webapplog.com/understanding-fat-arrows-in-coffeescript/) for example.

And ask the dev (if you know them) who wrote this code for an explanation of how it works.